# set focus to textarea in an angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that implements in-place editing. In its `link` function I have a watch that is supposed to set focus on the text box when editing is switched on:

```
$scope.$watch('view.enabled', function(value) {
  if (value) {
    var element = $element.find('input') || $element.find('textarea');
    var input = element && element[0];
    if (input) {
      $timeout(function() {
        input.focus()
      });
    }
  }
});
```

the directive can instantiate either an `input` element, or a `textarea` depending on the parameters. The problem is that invoking `focus()` on the `textarea` element does not set focus to it. For `input` elements it does set the focus though.

Here is plnkr. Please help.

[Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/743HUP?p=preview)

EDIT: using `autofocus` attribute on the `textarea` in HTML makes it get the focus, but I still do not understand why I cannot do it programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not set focus to the *textarea*. Try this:

```
if (input) {
    $timeout(function() {
        console.log(input);
        input.focus();
    });
}
```

It will give you this:

```
<input ng-show="editableType !== 'multi-line'" 
       ng-model="view.value" 
       class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-hide">
```

and not the *textarea*.
Quick fix (for *textarea* only) could be:

```
var element = $element.find('textarea');
```

---

Depending on order of things, I'm not sure if this would help:

```
var element = $element.find('textarea') || $element.find('input');
```

have to look closer at it ...

Comment: I feel stupid. Yes, of course. There are both elements in DOM... Need to check visibility or look for specific tag name depending on mode. Thanks!

Comment: @akonsu: An honest mistake ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think $timeout is a good way to focus the element on creation. You can split the "link" attribute can be split into "pre" and "post", for pre-link and post-link functions.

[Working Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Fj59GB](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fj59GB)

```js
// this is the directive you add to any element you want to highlight after creation
Guest.directive('autoFocus', function() {
    return {
        link: {
            pre: function preLink(scope, element, attr) {
                console.debug('prelink called');
                // this fails since the element hasn't rendered
                //element[0].focus();
            },
            post: function postLink(scope, element, attr) {
                console.debug('postlink called');
                // this succeeds since the element has been rendered
                element[0].focus();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```
<input value="hello" />
<!-- this input automatically gets focus on creation -->
<input value="world" auto-focus />
```

[Full AngularJS Directive Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile)